# How to style the popup element which shows on a textinput?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textinput

[image]

I am building my own custom search with google search api. 
How can I style the popup which shows when selecting an input box ?
Its some sort of search-input history popup.
I guess this may be only possible via jquery. But I dunno how this element is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style a history-complete dropdown. It's implemented differently on different browsers.

You can hide it if it doesn't match your site's design, by using `autocomplete="off"`

See duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

As Samuel Liew's answer indicates, this is browser functionality that you can't style. If you just don't want to show it, use `autocomplete="off"`. If you really want the functionality *and* you really need it to be styled, you'll have to roll your own, for example by storing a list of the user's previous inputs in a session or cookie value and using it to populate a list that you generate manually when the user enters text.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I would have been searching forever.